# Sum column based on date range from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, group-by

I have two tables.

**Transactions**

[image: Transactions]

**Date time range**

[image: Date time range]

I'm trying to sum Col1 for the transactions between (and including) each start and end time in table 2.

I'm expecting:

range 1 = 3
range 2 = 2
range 3 = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select dr.*,
       (select sum(t.col1)
        from transactions t
        where t.datetime >= dr.start and
              t.datetime <= dr.end
       ) as cnt
from daterange dr;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select Start, End, sum(Col1) from Transactions t inner join [Date time range] d on [datetime] between Start and End
group by Start, End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple JOIN and a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT ranges.id, ranges.start, ranges.end, SUM(transactions.col1)
FROM ranges
LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactions.datetime >= ranges.start AND
                          transactions.datetime <= ranges.end
GROUP BY ranges.id, ranges.start, ranges.end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, replacing the LEFT join if required.

```
select d.id,min(start),max(end), sum(isnull(t.col1,0.00)) 
from DateRange d
left join transactions t on 1=1 and t.dateime between d.start and d.end
group by d.id
```